# How to hide main form in VB

Tags: vb.net, forms, visual-studio

My goal is this: Program opens, small form initializes things, displaying text status updates as it does this, and when its done, it goes away and the actual main program form appears, allowing you to use it. Ive tried `Me.Hide()` and `Me.Visible = False` however both leave the initial small form open, with the actual program opened directly behind it. The small form is set as the main form to open to in VB config.

Comment: This is what a [SPLASH screen](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfkbc5a3(v=vs.100).aspx) is for.  All of the "initialization" work should be in the main form's Load() event.  While loading, the splash screen will remain visible; then the splash screen will automatically be closed and the main form opens.  For a **minimum splash display time**, set the [WindowsFormsApplicationBase.MinimumSplashScreenDisplayTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.applicationservices.windowsformsapplicationbase.minimumsplashscreendisplaytime(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a workaround. It will minimize the form and hide it from taskbar:

```vb
Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized
Me.ShowInTaskbar = False
```

Later, when you want to exit the application, do it in standard way: by closing this (hidden) form.

Comment: I need to have the window display text, and determine via an If statement, to either Hide the small window and display the main window, OR leave the small window open and open a different small window.

Comment: @CarlosAllende – and this is supposed to hide initial small window, if needed.

Comment: Alright, that worked to hide the initial small window, but now when I click X out on the second main big window, it is still running in the background

Comment: @CarlosAllende – on exiting the application, close that hidden form and the application will exit.